# Deleting an Element of a map with jpa

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-many

I'm trying to figure out for days now how I can remove a persisted element from a map. I found threads with similar problems, but none of them would help me finally.
Everything works fine, adding and persisting the element, editing and updating that element and so on. Except for deleting the element. I'm having a (time)schedule with 5 Maps for each weekday. Here are the essential parts of the code

Schedule:

```
@Entity
public class Schedule extends JPAEntity implements Serializable {

...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapKey(name = "hourTime")
    private Map<Integer, SchoolSubject> monday;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapKey(name = "hourTime")
    private Map<Integer, SchoolSubject> tuesday;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapKey(name = "hourTime")
    private Map<Integer, SchoolSubject> wednesday;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapKey(name = "hourTime")
    private Map<Integer, SchoolSubject> thursday;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "schedule", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    @MapKey(name = "hourTime")
    private Map<Integer, SchoolSubject> friday;

    public boolean removeSubject(final int index, final SchoolSubject oldSubject) {
        final String day = oldSubject.getWeekday();

        switch (day) {
        case "Montag":
            return monday.remove(index, oldSubject);
        case "Dienstag":
            return tuesday.remove(index, oldSubject);
        case "Mittwoch":
            return wednesday.remove(index, oldSubject);
        case "Donnerstag":
            return thursday.remove(index, oldSubject);
        case "Freitag":
            return friday.remove(index, oldSubject);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

SchoolSubject:

```
@Entity
public class SchoolSubject extends JPAEntity implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3554577133392512324L;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Basic
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int hourTime;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Schedule schedule;
```

JPAEntity:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@EntityListeners(JPAEntityListener.class)
public class JPAEntity {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
```

So my delete-Method in another logic-class is the following:

```
    @Override
    public void removeSubject(User user, Schedule schedule, SchoolSubject oldSubject) {
        if (schedule.removeSubject(oldSubject.getHourTime() - 1, oldSubject)) {
            schoolSubjectDAO.remove(oldSubject);
        }

        scheduleDAO.update(schedule);
        try {
            userDAO.update(user);
        } catch (final DuplicateUniqueFieldException e) {
            throw new UnexpectedUniqueViolationException(e);
        }
    }
```

I was debugging the method, I'm successfully removing the element from schedule. But `scheduleDAO.update(schedule)` doesn't seem to work fully. Like I said, everything else works flawlessly

**UPDATE**

I followed crizzis suggestions now, changing it to a unidirectional relationship, and removing the `SchoolSubject.schedule` field.

The updated Schedule class:

```
@Entity
public class Schedule extends JPAEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * Die eindeutige SerialisierungsID.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -3554837193392512324L;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKey(name = "hourTime")
    private Map<Integer, SchoolSubject> monday;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKey(name = "hourTime")
    private Map<Integer, SchoolSubject> tuesday;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKey(name = "hourTime")
    private Map<Integer, SchoolSubject> wednesday;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKey(name = "hourTime")
    private Map<Integer, SchoolSubject> thursday;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @MapKey(name = "hourTime")
    private Map<Integer, SchoolSubject> friday;
```

But with this I got a new error when adding a subject (which worked before). The adding operation is the following:

```
 public void addSubject(User user, Schedule schedule, SchoolSubject subject)
            throws DateAlreadyOccupiedException {
        schedule.addSubject(subject.getHourTime() - 1, subject);
        scheduleDAO.update(schedule);
        try {
            userDAO.update(user);
        } catch (final DuplicateUniqueFieldException e) {
            throw new UnexpectedUniqueViolationException(e);
        }
    }
```

The error I got is the following:

```
Severe:   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at de.unibremen.st.gradelog.filter.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2342)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2123)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy613.update(Unknown Source)
    at de.unibremen.st.gradelog.persistence.__EJB31_Generated__UserDAO__Intf____Bean__.update(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:434)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at de.unibremen.st.gradelog.persistence.UserDAO$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.update(Unknown Source)
    at de.unibremen.st.gradelog.businesslogic.ScheduleManager.addSubject(ScheduleManager.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy605.addSubject(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:434)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at de.unibremen.st.gradelog.businesslogic.IScheduleManager$1688850411$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.addSubject(Unknown Source)
    at de.unibremen.st.gradelog.controller.ScheduleBean.save(ScheduleBean.java:100)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:289)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.checkExceptionClientTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:666)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:511)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4566)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2074)
    ... 109 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'FRIDAY_ID'  cannot accept a NULL value.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO SCHEDULE_SCHOOLSUBJECT (monday_ID, Schedule_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="monday" sql="INSERT INTO SCHEDULE_SCHOOLSUBJECT (monday_ID, Schedule_ID) VALUES (?, ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:879)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.performPreQueryFlush(QueryImpl.java:967)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:473)
    at de.unibremen.st.gradelog.persistence.UserDAO.getUserForUsername(UserDAO.java:227)
    at de.unibremen.st.gradelog.persistence.UserDAO.update(UserDAO.java:151)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1081)
    at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1153)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4786)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.invokeBeanMethod(EjbInvocation.java:656)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.SessionBeanInterceptor.aroundInvoke(SessionBeanInterceptor.java:52)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor86.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.EjbInvocation.proceed(EjbInvocation.java:608)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.doCall(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:163)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.SystemInterceptorProxy.aroundInvoke(SystemInterceptorProxy.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor93.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeInterceptor.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:883)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.AroundInvokeChainImpl.invokeNext(InterceptorManager.java:822)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.interceptors.InterceptorManager.intercept(InterceptorManager.java:369)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:4758)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:4746)
    at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:212)
    ... 107 more
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.6.1.v20150605-31e8258): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'FRIDAY_ID'  cannot accept a NULL value.
Error Code: 20000
Call: INSERT INTO SCHEDULE_SCHOOLSUBJECT (monday_ID, Schedule_ID) VALUES (?, ?)
    bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: DataModifyQuery(name="monday" sql="INSERT INTO SCHEDULE_SCHOOLSUBJECT (monday_ID, Schedule_ID) VALUES (?, ?)")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:331)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:902)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:964)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:633)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:560)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:2055)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:251)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.StatementQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(StatementQueryMechanism.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:904)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.internalExecuteQuery(AbstractSession.java:3267)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1857)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1839)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToManyMapping.insertAddedObjectEntry(ManyToManyMapping.java:630)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.mappings.ManyToManyMapping.performDataModificationEvent(ManyToManyMapping.java:838)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.CommitManager.commitAllObjectsWithChangeSet(CommitManager.java:160)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.writeAllObjectsWithChangeSet(AbstractSession.java:4260)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabase(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1441)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.commitToDatabaseWithPreBuiltChangeSet(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:1587)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.writeChanges(RepeatableWriteUnitOfWork.java:455)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.flush(EntityManagerImpl.java:874)
    ... 141 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'FRIDAY_ID'  cannot accept a NULL value.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SQLExceptionFactory40.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException.getSQLException(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.PreparedStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(PreparedStatementWrapper.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeDirectNoSelect(DatabaseAccessor.java:892)
    ... 164 more
Caused by: org.apache.derby.client.am.SqlException: Column 'FRIDAY_ID'  cannot accept a NULL value.
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.Statement.completeExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.parseEXCSQLSTTreply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetStatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.StatementReply.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.net.NetPreparedStatement.readExecute_(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.readExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.flowExecute(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.derby.client.am.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateX(Unknown Source)
    ... 167 more
```

Comment: can you add the removeSubject impl and also, do you perform merge before update?

Comment: Yep, I updated the class Schedule with the method, but like I said, while debugging, there didn't seem to be a problem with that method. It was successfully removing the object from the map of the entity. The merge is actually performed by scheduleDAO.update(schedule) which is basicially the merge() method from `javax.persistence.EntityManager` When adding an element, and performing scheduleDAO.update(schedule) everything works fine

Comment: I see. What persistence provider are you using? and what is the version?

Comment: It's EliclipseLink (JPA 2.1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reuse `mappedBy` like that. After you persist `Schedule` and try to load it from the db, JPA has no way of knowing which of the `SchoolSubject` entities go to `monday`, which ones go to `tuesday` and so on. What you're trying to do is to map one side of the relationship (`SchoolSubject.schedule`) onto multiple inverse sides (`Schedule.monday, Schedule.tuesday, ...`). This is illegal in JPA.

The only way of implementing the mapping you want that I can think of is using a **unidirectional** relationship (preferably **without the joining column**) like so:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@MapKey(name = "hourTime")
private Map<Integer, SchoolSubject> monday;
...
```

You also need to remove the `SchoolSubject.schedule` field altogether (as an alternative, to keep the relationship bidirectional, you would need one field in `SchoolSubject` per each day of week, but I'm guessing that's not what you want).

This way, JPA will keep the relation between `Schedule` and `SchoolSubject` in separate join tables, one per each day of the week (so that they don't get mixed up). If you absolutely need the join column approach, use a separate join column (`monday_id`, `tuesday_id` etc.) for each mapping (do **not** use the same column name, and do **not** use the primary key column, which I'm assuming the column named `id` is).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I'm trying to approach the problem like you said, I get an sql exception saying that the column FRIDAY_ID cannot accept a NULL value. I'm really not experienced in database operations yet, how should I proceed now? Would it help if I post the whole error trace?

Comment: It would help if you posted the updated code. I forgot to mention that in the above setup, you cannot declare the join column as `nullable=false` (nor can you use the `optional=false` flag on the `@ManyToOne` side, should you decide to go with the 'field per day of week' approach)

Comment: I updated the new code. I don't ave the `@ManyToOne` relation as you suggested and no join column with `nullable=false` 
So what could it be?

Comment: According to the current mapping, the `SCHEDULE_SCHOOLSUBJECT` table should no longer exist. Are you sure you recreated the entire db schema from scratch after the update? Also, try adding `@JoinTable(name= 'schedule_monday')`, `@JoinTable(name= 'schedule_tuesday')` (and so on) to each of the mappings.

Comment: BTW the line `schedule.addSubject(subject.getHourTime() - 1, subject);` suggests that the map key under which `subject` will be stored will differ from the value of `subject.hourTime`. Is this intentional? You do realize that after loading the map back from the persistent store using JPA, the keys **will correspond** to the value of `subject.hourTime`?

Comment: Also, you did remember to remove the `schedule` field from `SchoolSubject`, right?

Comment: Thanks ahead for giving this effort helping
Yes I was making sure recreating the db tables. And `SCHEDULE_SCHOOLSUBJECT` was definetly created from that. Also the `schedule.addSubject(subject.getHourTime() - 1, subject)` is correct that way, as I want to have the first class hour on index position 0 and so on. While debugging I was making sure there was also nothing wrong with that.
However I was trying your suggestions with @JoinTable(name= "SCHEDULE_MONDAY") and so on. Adding a subject was no problem anymore. But when deleting, it acutally did nothing, nor I got a error message. Rly weird

Comment: You designated the `hourTime` field to be used as the map key. This means that after you save the data and retrieve it, JPA will use the value of that field when populating the map. When you save the map, JPA simply ignores the value of the map keys - **it relies on the value of `hourTime` only**. It shouldn't be surprising that deleting the entry using `remove(key, value)` doesn't work - you're giving the method a wrong key as a parameter. The solution is to keep the field specified in `@MapKey` in sync with the actual map key under which the entity is stored.

Comment: Jesus, now I feel really silly approaching it that way, now I don't know why I went that way. *facepalm*
And thank you so much! You want to post an answer which I can accept?